# How to make put request with nested dictionaries to flask-restful?

Tags: python-3.x, api, dictionary, flask

The documentation example for a simple restful api is:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
todos = {}
class TodoSimple(Resource):
    def get(self, todo_id):
        return {todo_id: todos[todo_id]}
    def put(self, todo_id):
        todos[todo_id] = request.form['data']
        return {todo_id: todos[todo_id]}

api.add_resource(TodoSimple, '/<string:todo_id>')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0",port="80",debug=True)
```

However, suppose I made a put request with a nested dictionary,ie `{'data':{'fruit':'orange'}}`. The TodoSimple would have `request.form.to_dict() = {'data':'fruit'}`. How can I work with the full nested dictionary?

Comment: how are you testing the api? `request.form.to_dict()` gives `{'data':{'fruit':'orange'}}` , works

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use Schemas to achieve this goal. Take a good look at this first example of marshmallow docs:

https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/

> **As flask-restful docs says:**
>
> The whole request parser part of Flask-RESTful is slated for removal
> and will be replaced by documentation on how to integrate with other
> packages that do the input/output stuff better (such as marshmallow).